# Bottom margin of last child gets hidden when overflow applies

Tags: google-chrome, margin, css

I have a container div which has children anchored to the bottom. The problem is that when the div's overflow scrollbar appears, the bottom margin of the last child gets hidden.

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/TxEAP/3/. At first, there's a correct margin underneath the `1` div. Clicking "append one" so that the scrollbar eventually appears makes the last div not have a bottom margin anymore. Opening DevTools shows that the margin of that last child is there, but it is outside of the container's viewport, even when scrolling completely to the bottom.

How can this be solved? It would suffice to get this working in Google Chrome.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <!-- several of these .item divs -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.item {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}​
```

Comment: I believe there should be other ways to prevent margin collapse than with `-webkit-margin-collapse: separate`...

Comment: @BoltClock: That was a leftover from my previous tries. It doesn't seem to make any difference to the issue however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my final solution using flexbox. It's supported well enough on Chrome despite all `-webkit-` prefixes. Basically, the idea is to have a dummy element that, in case of no overflow, fills up the space of the container starting from the top (so that the real children are anchored to the bottom); in case of overflow, it is hidden automatically because of `height: 0`. It does not suffer from the margin issue, and it does not collapse margins.

http://jsfiddle.net/mCYLm/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="gap-filler"></div>
    <div class="item">foo</div>
    <!-- more `div.item`s -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.main {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

div.main div.gap-filler {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    height: 0;
}

div.main div.item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}​
```

---

**Edit:** This was a solution without flexbox, but it had selection issues.

A solution that eventually worked was the following: http://jsfiddle.net/TxEAP/7/. This appends hidden "content" which makes Chrome not hide the margin of the last `.item` div.

```
.container:after {
    content: "";
    font-size: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
}
```

---

**Edit:** The following only works if `display: inline-block` is possible.

Finally I found a solution. If all `.items` have `display: inline-block` *except* the first one, then the margin does not get hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/TxEAP/5/

```
.item:not(:first-child) {
    display: inline-block;

    /* attempt at getting `width: auto` like `display: block` has */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 2 * 15px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: +1 nice solution. I experimented with `box-sizing` myself but your flexbox solution is simple and JavaScript-free :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you just move the `overflow-y: scroll;` from `.main.` to `.container` class then the margin is preserved. The only drawback is for less than 3 items (for the given container height) you get a small scrollbar placeholder, instead of a full height one.

<strike>Removing `max-height:100%` on the container seems to fix it for my test in Chrome 21.</strike>

Moving the properties so that the overflow is on the container, preserves the margin/padding for an element added to the end that results in the scrollbar appearing.

```
.main {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that throws away the scrollbar.

Comment: If the `.main` and `.container` CSS can be altered, my updated solution might work for you.

Comment: I'm trying your solution now. However this time the divs are not anchored to the bottom anymore it seems. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry I need to be away for a while. I'll try for a solution later unless someone else has already answered :-)

Comment: One more attempt at this. I think I'm out of ideas now!

Comment: Thanks, that works. The scrollbar is now growing when the overflow does not yet apply, though. But it looks great!

Comment: Yes that's the drawback unfortunately. If the height of the items is known you could set `overflow-y:hidden` in CSS and dynamically set `overflow-y:scroll` based on the number of items using JavaScript - in the example, adding `if (i >= 2) $('.container').css({overflowY:'scroll'});` before adding the item works for me - see [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TxEAP/8/)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for all your help. I've upvoted your answer and accepted my own, because that was the answer I eventually implemented.